# How to retrieve integer value from field in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to retrieve integer data from a field, it is a mobile number field which accepts only numbers.

This is my code

```
 WebElement FatherNum= driver.findElement(By.id("fatherMobile")); 
 FatherNum.clear(); FatherNum.sendKeys("1234567890"); 
 FatherNum.getAttribute("value"); 
 System.out.println(FatherNum);
```

getting in FatherNum :

```
 [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (17b4c2e854f9f3083a87d4654f52228d)] -> id: fatherMobile]
```

Comment: You should provide your own failed attempt in your question, otherwise this just reads as *gimme teh codez*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code you are trying to print the element itself.

```
 System.out.println(FatherNum);
```

If you want to print the value of that field , you can do it by :

```
 System.out.println(FatherNum.getAttribute("value"));
```

**OR**

```
 String Fathernum= FatherNum.getAttribute("value"); 
 System.out.println(Fathernum);
```

See the doc for getAttribute - [see link](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Are you able to get the value using the above code?